# How to run a load test using Jmeter while Fiddler is running?

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, fiddler

I want to execute a load test using Jmeter while Fiddler is recording the transactions that is currently happening. How do I do it? And is it possible to send the fiddler trace log during my jmeter test execution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it in a simple way.

Just execute the fiddler and enable trace on it for your application that you want to test so that unwanted traces can be ignored. This can be done using the proxy setup.

https://www.codementor.io/aydindev/introduction-to-using-fiddler-for-debug-http-s-requests-djf60hjsf

Now after everything is setup you can execute your jmeter script to load test your application.